# How to get specific div content from another website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xmlhttprequest

I want to get a websites table contents from their site to my site. I'm getting the `innerHTML` by the following function:

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            createDiv(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, false );
    xmlhttp.send();    
}


document.write(httpGet("https://cors.io/?http://crystalmathlabs.com/tracker-rs3/currenttop.php"));

function createDiv(responsetext)
{
    var _body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var _div = document.createElement('div');
    _div.innerHTML = responsetext;
    _body.appendChild(_div);
}
```

So this basically copies the site page without all the styling and images and stuff which is fine, but I want to reduce it to just the tables using a specific class name. I was thinking of a couple of ways to do this...

1. Doing something to the URL to block out all the elements except the tables I want, I'm not even sure if this is possible.
2. Filtering out everything from the response text. It returns a string so I think I would need some major string manipulation to do this.
3. Make a temporary `div` so I can manipulate everything through jQuery and JS which is a bit of a hacky way but i think it will work.

What would be the best way to do this? Or maybe an idea I haven't mentioned yet.

Comment: added an answer, see if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `DocumentFragment` function [**`createDocumentFragment.`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment)

Add all the HTML you received to the `documentFragment` and then select the desired HTML elements just like you would select from the document, using `doucument.querySelector()` for fragment you use `fragment.querySelector()`

DocumentFragments allow developers to place child elements onto an arbitrary node-like parent, allowing for node-like interactions without a true root node.  Doing so allows developers to produce structure without doing so within the visible DOM -- an increase of speed is the true advantage.

I would start from the `HTML` received and use a dummy HTML and select `table.my-class` and add to a custom div you can modify it according to your needs.

```js
var html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>HTML Tutorial</title>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<table class="my-class">
<tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>`;

$(function() {
  let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  let temp = document.createElement('div');
  temp.innerHTML = html;
  fragment.appendChild(temp);
  var table = fragment.querySelector('table.my-class');
  document.querySelector('.preview').append(table);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preview">
</div>
```

Comment: hmm its not ideal but i think its the best im going to get, thanks

Comment: what makes you think it's not ideal for your situation where you have a bunch of nested HTML and you need to select a few elements from them, you cant select from the html received as it won't be treated as html but text, this IS the way to do it. @RachelDockter

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your use case can accomodate server side code but a very nice Node package which can solve this scenario is x-ray.

By doing this on server-side you avoid CORS issues and by using Node as your server, you still will be writing everything in JS.

x-ray also gives you a very nice option like jquery to point the exact html node you want to capture from the response HTML.

Check here for details:[x-ray](https://www.npmjs.com/package/x-ray)

Comment: I wasnt planning on having any sort of server for this, although node js would be my go to. Im avoiding the CORS issue by putting the request through a 3rd party which i dont mind doing. U can see it before the URL in my example

Comment: @RachelDockter, just checked cors.io. it's a pretty nice utility you are using.